# Turn Off Filter Metric In Google Analytics Pull?

Tags: python, google-analytics

I'm incorporating a Google Analytics pull for several different profiles. Some include a filter, others do not. I'd like to know what I can pass into the filters argument to do nothing (like None or ""), but both return an error.

Here's the code I am running:

```
  return service.data().ga().get(
        ids='ga:' + profile_id,
        start_date=start_date,
        end_date=end_date,
        metrics=metrics,
        dimensions=dimensions,
        filters=filters,
        segment=segment,
        samplingLevel='HIGHER_PRECISION',
        start_index=str(pag_index + 1),
        max_results=str(pag_index + 10000)).execute()
```

This seems like a simple issue, but I can't get a straight answer if there's a way to set the filters argument as something to *not* filter. Otherwise, I can write an if statement and have two separate calls, but naturally would prefer not to have this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can try defaulting the filter to something like:

```
ga:pagepath=~.*
```

That's essentially a filter for any page path, thus everything.

Note this could trigger sampling, depends on how much traffic you have on your site.